# Deleting entire data from a particular column in oracle-sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

Recently I have started learning `Oracle-sql`. I know that with the help of `DELETE` command we can delete a particular row(s). So, Is it possible to delete entire data from a particular column in a table using only `DELETE` command. (I know that using `UPDATE` command by setting null values to entire column we can achieve the functionality of `DELETE`).

Comment: `UPDATE table SET your_column_name = NULL` DELETE removes rows, alternatively you can get rid of column using `ALTER table DROP COLUMN name` (not recommended)

Comment: @lad2025 Thank you. Now I clearly understood that DELETE removes only rows but not entire data from a particular column.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**[DELETE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems014.htm)**

> The DELETE statement **removes entire rows** of data from a specified
>   table or view

If you want to "remove" data from particular column update it:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET your_column_name = NULL;
```

or if column is `NOT NULL`

```
UPDATE table_name
SET your_column_name = <value_indicating_removed_data>;
```

You can also remove entire column using DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;
```

Comment: What do you mean by <value_indicating_removed_data> ?.

Comment: @RajeeVVenkaT For example your column is set to `NOT NULL` and you have column name, you can for example set ` ` empty string

Comment: I observed that a column when set NOT NULL cannot be updated with ' '. So, only by using DROP or UNUSED command we can perform actions.

Comment: Now I understood. Column when set NOT NULL cannot be updated with    ' ' but can be updated with '<space> '. Small difference, but matters a lot.

Comment: @RajeeVVenkaT Yes, because Oracle treats internally empty string as  NULL

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, `delete` deletes rows not columns.

You have three options in Oracle:

- Set all the values to `NULL` using update.
- Remove the column from the table.
- Set the column to unused.

The last two use `alter table`:

```
alter table t drop column col;
alter table t set unused (col);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Invisible Type, which is from an ***oracle 12cR2***.

```
ALTER TABLE LOG1
MODIFY operation  INVISIBLE
```

It is  a better than drop of a particular column.If you need to visible you can get back by altering with an `VISIBLE` of a column name.

Answer (score -1):

`update employee set commission=nvl2(commission,'','')`

this will remove all the data from the column